# NPM install: Platform Toolset = v141 cannot be found

Tags: c++, node.js, visual-studio, npm

I'm trying to install this library [Barcode-Scanner-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/barcode-scanner) but the installation fails and displays this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(57,5): error MSB8020: The build t
ools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found. To build using the v141 build tools, please install v141 bui
ld tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-cli
ck the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\bla\Desktop\bla\myProject\node_modules\@serialport\bin
dings\build\bindings.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\bla\Desktop\bla\myProject\node_modules\@serialport\bindings
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN myProject@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN myProject@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @serialport/bindings@2.0.2 install: `prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @serialport/bindings@2.0.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bla\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-10T10_13_47_454Z-debug.log
```

I tried some solutions I found on the web like installing this:

```
npm i windows-build-tools
```

but it doesn't work for me.

I got VS2017 installed and also the Platform Toolset v141 as you can see here (last checkbox): [VS17 Updater](https://gyazo.com/3207242a2bf4fed60dbefd1dc0761f9d)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing windows-build-tools this way

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a `cmd.exe` and see, what version of MSBuild is on your path. If there is one and it is an older version (as was the case for me), remove it from the path - at least for the time of your npm install - and try again.

See also my answer here for slightly more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300218/709537